# How to search a dollar sign in a string in R?

Tags: regex, r

I have dataset with a column which has strings in it,

example

"Managed a budget of $250,000, utilizing Excel to monitor and compare operating expenses with previous budgets resulting in a 10% budget savings for the company"

I want to flag all the strings which have a dollar sign followed by a number.

I am trying to code like this

```
grep("$[^0-9]", cand_emp$description, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = FALSE, value = FALSE,
           fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE, invert = FALSE)
```

It seems , it is not the right way to code.

Any help highly appreciated

Thanks!
Parth

Comment: Use  \\ or `[$]` to escape the metacharacter.  `grep("\\$[0-9]", str1)`

Comment: Or change to `fixed = TRUE`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since dollar sign is a special character you have to escape it by preceding a backslash like this:

```
\$
```

You can check the **[documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html)**

> The fundamental building blocks are the regular expressions that match a single character. Most characters, including all letters and digits, are regular expressions that match themselves. Any metacharacter with special meaning may be quoted by preceding it with a backslash. The metacharacters in extended regular expressions are . \ | ( ) [ { ^ $ * + ?, but note that whether these have a special meaning depends on the context.

**Update**: as **[Gregor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/903061/gregor)** pointed in his comment, you have to escape the backslash in R, so you have to use:

```
\\$
```

You could have:

```
grep("\\$[^0-9]", cand_emp$description, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = FALSE, value = FALSE,
       fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE, invert = FALSE)
```

On the other hand, if you don't like having the two backslashes, you can leverage the character class using ``` [``] ``` by having:

```
grep("[$][^0-9]", cand_emp$description, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = FALSE, value = FALSE,
       fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE, invert = FALSE)
```

**Update**: I noticed that you updated your question with *I want to flag all the strings which have a dollar sign followed by a number*. For this you have to remove the `^` from your example, use:

```
[$][0-9]+
```

Comment: In R, you'll have to escape the backslash with another backslash, `\\$`.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep("\\$[^0-1000000000]", cand_emp$description, ignore.case = TRUE, perl = FALSE, value = FALSE,
                       fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE, invert = FALS
```

E)

Thanks Fede, the above code worked

Comment: `[^0-1000000000]` does not do what you expect! And you don't need all those extra parameters ...